# What does this line of code do in Kilobot example?

Tags: c, robotics

I've been trying out some example on the Kilobots especially the [Synchronization of LEDS](https://github.com/acornejo/kilobot-labs/blob/master/README.md#lab5-sync). I have come across this code in the example.

```
uint8_t offsets[32];

void message_rx(message_t *msg, distance_measurement_t *d) {
    if (modulo_clock > msg->data[0]) {
        if (modulo_clock - msg->data[0] < 16)
            offsets[modulo_clock-msg->data[0]]++;
    } else {
        if (msg->data[0] - modulo_clock > 16)
            offsets[modulo_clock + (32-msg->data[0])]++;
    }
}
```

I just want to know what does `offsets[modulo_clock-msg->data[0]]++` and `offsets[modulo_clock + (PERIOD-msg->data[0])]++` do in the code as I know that they are arrays but just confused of the usage here.

Comment: Increment the `offsets` array element whose index is calculated inside the outermost `[]`.

Comment: Overall, provided that `msg->data[0]` is close enough to `modulo_clock`, an element of the `offsets` array is chosen based on their relative values, and the value of that element is incremented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `offsets` is array of integers
- `modulo_clock - msg->data[0]` is a number used as index to array `offsets`
- with this `offsets[modulo_clock - msg->data[0]]` you access number in `offsets`
- and finally `++` is an operator for increment

So together `offsets[modulo_clock-msg->data[0]]++` just increments (add +1) the number in `offsets` in position `modulo_clock-msg->data[0]`.

That same is for `offsets[modulo_clock + (PERIOD-msg->data[0])]++`.